# Adjust iframe to embedded facebook video's original height / aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, iframe

I am trying to embed Facebook videos on my website. However like many before me I am struggling with sizing them.

Following [the official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/), I realized that the first way of doing it (with the js SDK) provided an easy method to have adjustable videos, but was about twice as slow as using the iframe. But of course in the latter case, only the width of the video will adjust to its container.

I tried accessing the iframe's data to fetch the video's original height and CSS to adjust its width based on code samples I found on the internet, but can't due to same origin policy.

https://codepen.io/Angc/pen/ExYGNOO

```html
<div class="root">
<div id="35-365098" class="embed-iframe-facebook">
  <div>
    <iframe id="iframe-35-365098" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdestanie.wagner%2Fvideos%2F2391334934255393%2F&amp;show_text=0" style="border:none;" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0"> </iframe>

  </div>
  <span class="origin-url" hidden="">https://www.facebook.com/destanie.wagner/videos/2391334934255393/</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.embed-iframe-facebook {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.embed-iframe-facebook div {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 178%;
}

.embed-iframe-facebook iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Furthermore, I can't seem to find a way to tell the iframe to "adjust its size to its content". Ideally I would want to do that, and detect its height so I can adjust its width, to create an artificial "max-height".

**My question is therefore:** how can I have the iframe adjust its height to the embedded video ?

Comment: No, you have no JavaScript access to the content of the iframe at all, because it is loaded from a different domain (Same Origin Policy.) The SDK can do cross-domain communication in the background, and is able to adapt element sizes dynamically that way.

Comment: I know, I mentioned SOP in my question. But there could be some indirect way to access the iframe's content size (as in, the iframe is a black box, but the box still has an effect on its environment).

Comment: The communication between the iframe and the SDK works via `postMessage`, I think; that is how the iframe communicates the height of its content to the SDK code running in your page. If(!) the version that gets embedded via the iframe directly does that as well, you could try and listen to those messages yourself, using your own custom JS code.

Comment: Now that sounds like an interesting piece of information, do you have any source where I could read more about it ?

Comment: From the FB side of things, no - I don’t think these internals are documented anywhere. I’d start by setting up a message listener, as described here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#The_dispatched_event, log the event details to console, and see what happens.

Comment: Go to the documentation page you listed above, and execute `window.addEventListener("message", function (event) { console.log(event) }, false);` via the browser console. Then change the width of the plugin in the generator, you should see several MessageEvents getting logged, one of them containing `data` with a string like `"type=resize&width=450&height=252&cb=f2c5a44747b7aec&domain=developers.facebook.com&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ff1babf41e83d78&relation=parent.parent"`

Comment: The `f1babf41e83d78` part in the `origin` value appears to correspond to the `name` attribute Facebook set on the iframe; how the whole thing behaves when the iframe was not generated by the SDK though, and embedded by yourself instead, you’d have to test.

Comment: When using the SDK, there are indeed a few messages caught, including a resize message that shows us the requested width and the generated height, but sadly nothing when directly embedding the iframe. I guess I will just have to store the video's size on the first load, and build the iframe based on that. It was quite an interesting discover nonetheless, thanks for that !

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to let an iFrame fill its parent div.

For example:

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    height: 100vw;
}
.iframeContainer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
}
.embed-area {
    clear: both;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

And use the following HTML markup.

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="embed-area">
            <div class="iframeContainer">
               <!-- Render the iFrame in this div. -->
               <!-- It will now fill up the div, unless other style rules are preventing it. -->
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although my question was the opposite: have the iframe adjust to its content. I edited my question for clarity.